# Passing Facebook login information to the second view

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

This is a 2 part question.

1.) Once the user login to the application i want to navigate to `DashboardViewController`. However, i am ending up with a warning.

> Warning: Attempt to present 
>   on  whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

How to solve this?

2.) I want to pass `(id<FBGraphUser>)user` to the `DashboardViewController`, How can i achieve this?

The code is as follows:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //[self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Private method implementation

-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePicture.hidden = shouldHide;
}


#pragma mark - FBLoginView Delegate method implementation

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{



    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged in.";

    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
}



-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;
    self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
    self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
//

    [self performSelector:@selector(displayDashboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}

-(void)displayDashboard{
    DashboardViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashboardSegue"];

    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}




-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged out";

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
}


-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"OKKKKK %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);

}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your originating view controller, prepare your upcoming view controller using the prepareForSegue method. I actually have the same scenario as you, and this is what I do:

Extend your `DashboardViewController` object to include a new property, where you can store the user information:

```
@property (nonatomic) id<FBGraphUser> *fbUserInfo;
```

Configure a segue between your originating view controller and your dashboard VC.

In your originating view controller, add a method that will trigger this segue:

```
- (void)displayAnotherVC:(YourClass *)post {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCommentsSegue" sender:post];
}
```

In your originating VC, overrider the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"]){
            YourCustomViewController *userProfileViewController = (YourCustomViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            userProfileViewController.yourUserInfoProperty = (YourClass *)sender;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unable to add a Segue because its not a UIButton but a View that's in place.

Comment: @Illep Hi. You should be able to add a segue from your originating view controller to your dashboard view controller, in your case (I suppose) from the VC that prompts for the login to the dashboard VC. Your login controller surely has a way to identify when the login event completed successfully, and it's there where you can can trigger the performSegueWithIdentifier method.